# Run an iOS app with the same bundle ID with different accounts for development

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning, codesign

I don't have a paid Apple developer membership, and the app I'm building is far from the app store phase... So buying membership is not yet an option, unless strictly necessary.

There is another person who has to run the app on his phone. We're working remotely and far away from each other so plugging his phone into my laptop every now and then is out of the question.

We have separate Apple accounts.

We must use the same Bundle ID when running the app on phones due to licensing issues for a third party framework that our app depends on.

This worked just fine on Xcode 7:

- Normal development on my phone, my laptop, my developer account; same bundle ID.
- Other person will pull the latest code, compile and run on their Macbook, iPhone and their developer account; same Bundle ID.

But after updating to Xcode 8, it started complaining about the development account having no access to the Bundle ID (on the second laptop). I figured there's an option to invite other people if you have paid membership, but is there anything I can do to make it work without paying for the membership?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't invite others in your team in the free membership. You can either

- upgrade one account to paid,
- share one free dev account or
- still use Xcode 7 for the development.